# The application worked fine to download data from internet with real device but does not work to download data from internet with bluestacks

Tags: android, bluestacks

1 - I tested several applications with bluestacks and all worked fine to download data from internet
2 - I tested my application on real device and worked fine to download data from internet
3 - I tested my application with bluestacks and it does not work to download data from internet

It seems something is wrong with my application code but the point is it still worked with a real device

the code:

```
public class JSONHttpHandler3 {
    private static final String TAG = JSONHttpHandler3.class.getSimpleName();

    public JSONHttpHandler3() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall3(String FileNewName,String FileDestination,String sourceFileUri) {

        int serverResponseCode = 0;
        String fileName = FileNewName;
        String upLoadServerUri = null;
        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = FileDestination;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + sourceFileUri);
            return "0";
        }
        else {

            try {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);


                int length = fileInputStream.available();

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("BBBuploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "AAAServer Response is: " + total.toString() + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

                if (total.toString().contains("Move successful") == true )
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Move To Server successful");
                    return "Move To Server successful";
                }

                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Move To Server Failed");
                    return "Move To Server Failed";
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                return "Move To Server Failed";
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "111Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                return "Move To Server Failed";

            }
        }
    } // End else block
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem is a flag which was previously registered in the real mobile set was checked in the download process and since bluestacks did not have that flag registered, the download process had problem